# Cherrypy and JSON Arduino web interface

Tags: python, arduino, cherrypy

EDIT #2: So guess what, I'm almost there! I am facing what seems to be the last of my problems, well, as long as programming is concerned.
This is actually very interesting, I never ran into such a thing before.
The matter is in the following code, my javascript function. I usually never post for problems that seem very simple to solve, but I really have no idea what's going on here.

The issue seems to be in the first condition of the update function. See the line that says alert('hey'); ? Well, if I erase that line, for some unknown reason, nothing is sent to the action function. Nor to the Arduino, to the console... Just nothing happens. It's absolutely fascinating, as I like to call it. I have no idea. I thought maybe the alert() created some kind of delay that was necessary to read the arduino output, but when i create a delay with setTimeout, nothing happens either. It's incredible.

Just one more time: without the alert, the action function is not called, I checked by making the function print something if it's called. Nothing is printed, nothing. It's just not called. But with the alert, the function is called and the arduino turns on the LED.

Do you have any explanation? Here is my code:

```
function update(command=0) {
// if command send it
if (command!=0) {
    $.getJSON('/action?command='+command);
    alert('hey');
}

// read no matter what
$.getJSON('/read', {}, function(data) {
    if (data.state != 'failure' && data.content != '') {
        $('.notice').text(data.content);
        $('.notice').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout(function () { $('.notice').fadeOut(1000); }, 1500);
    }
    setTimeout(update, 5000);
});
}

update();
```

I am attempting to create a web interface accessible from any computer to control my Arduino.
I'm getting closer. One of my problems is that, using the following code, when I press a button to send a command to the Arduino, the Arduino does get it (the [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) blinks as configured), then does send a message, and the [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) script does retrieve the data, but it does NOT display it properly. The string misses some characters, and `index.html` is not returned as desired.

Basically, a function is called when a button is pressed, and I need to return the result of the function in a different function than the one the result was generated from.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cherrypy, functools, json, uuid, serial, threading, webbrowser, time

try:
    ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
    time.sleep(2)
    ser.write('1')
except:
    print('Arduino not detected. Moving on')

INDEX_HTML = open('index.html', 'r').read()

def timeout(func, args = (), kwargs = {}, timeout_duration = 10, default = None):
    class InterruptableThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.result = default
        def run(self):
            self.result = func(*args, **kwargs)

    it = InterruptableThread()
    it.start()
    it.join(timeout_duration)
    if it.isAlive():
        return it.result
    else:
        return it.result

def get_byte(useless):
    return ser.read().encode('Utf-8')

def json_yield(command):
    @functools.wraps(command)
    def _(self, command):
        if (command == 'Turn the LED on'):
            ser.write('2')
            time.sleep(2)
            print('wrote to port')
        print('ok, ok')
        try:
            m = ''
            while 1:
                print('reading...')
                byte = timeout(get_byte, ('none',), timeout_duration = 5)
                if byte == '*' or byte == None: break
                m = m + byte
            content = m
            time.sleep(1)
            return json.dumps({'state': 'ready', 'content':content})
        except StopIteration:
            return json.dumps({'state': 'done', 'content': None})
    return _

class DemoServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return INDEX_HTML

    @cherrypy.expose
    @json_yield
    def yell(self):
        yield 'nothing'

    @cherrypy.expose
    @json_yield
    def command(self):
        yield 'nothing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Timer(0.5, webbrowser.open, args=('http://localhost:8080',))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    cherrypy.quickstart(DemoServer(), config='config.conf')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I did'nt think about telling you about that in your previous question, but a while back I wrote a software called [pyaler](http://pythonhosted.org/pyaler/) that does exactly what you want (except it did not support long polling requests, as it is (was?) a wsgi limitation).

To answer your question, why don't you make your form a javascript query that sends the action, and gets the result as JSON that you can parse and update your current page with the result? That's way more elegant, simple and 2013...

Sadly I can't really tell, given your code, why you're not getting the result. It's too much over-sophisticated to understand if it really does what you want it to do... KISS!

Avoid doing anything at the module scope, except if you put it in `if __name__ == "__main__"`, or the day you'll want to extend your module by importing it, you'll execute incidentally some code, and it forces making a better design for your code.

You can take the `InterruptableThread()` class out of your timeout function, and give it the `default` as a parameter. `InterruptableThread(default)` and `def __init__(self, default): self.result = default`. But talking about that part, why do you do such over-sophisticated thing whereas you got a [`timeout` argument](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.__init__) you can use in when you create your serial connection?

Here is a slight modification I'd make to your code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cherrypy, functools, json, uuid, serial, threading, webbrowser, time

def arduino_connect(timeout=0):
    try:
        ser=serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=timeout)
        time.sleep(2)
        ser.write('1')
        return ser
    except:
        raise Exception('Arduino not detected. Moving on')

class ArduinoActions(object):
    def __init__(self, ser):
        self.ser = ser

    def get_data(self):
        content = ""
        while True:
            print('reading...')
            data = self.ser.read().encode('utf-8')
            if not data or data == '*':
                return content
            content += data

    def turn_led_on(self):
        ser.write('2')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('wrote led on to port')

    def turn_led_off(self):
        ser.write('2') # Replace with the value to tur the led off
        time.sleep(2) 
        print('wrote to led off port')

class DemoServer(ArduinoActions):
    def __init__(self, ser):
        ArduinoActions.__init__(self, ser)
        with open('index.html', 'r') as f:
            self.index_template = f.read()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return self.index_template

    @cherrypy.expose
    def action(self, command):
        state = 'ready'
        if command == "on":
            content = self.turn_led_on()
        elif command == "off":
            content = self.turn_led_off()
        else:
            content = 'unknown action'
            state = 'failure'
        return {'state': state, 'content': content}

    @cherrypy.expose
    def read(self):
        content = self.get_data()
        time.sleep(1)
        # set content-type to 'application/javascript'
        return content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = arduino_connect(5)
    # t = threading.Timer(0.5, webbrowser.open, args=('http://localhost:8080',))
    # t.daemon = True
    # t.start()
    cherrypy.quickstart(DemoServer(), config='config.conf')
```

In your javascript code, you you're calling the `yell` resource that returns literally nothing. 
You'd better make an `action` method (as I modified the given python code) and a separate `read()` method.
So you the `action` method will act on the arduino by writing bytes, thus commands to the arduino, and the
`read` method will read the output.

As the webserver may create parallel calls to the read/write method on the serial object, and
you can't read in parallel the same object, you may want to make an independant thread, by creating
a new class that inherits from `threading.Thread`, you implement an infinite loop reading the output
of the serial (by giving the serial object as parameter to that class' `__init__` function).
Then you push each new `content` data to a `list`, if you want to keep a log of all previous data, or
a `Queue.Queue` if you want only the last reading returned. Then from `ArduinoActions`, in the `read()` 
method you just need to return that `list` that will grow with any new reading from the arduino, and
thus make a log of all the data (or get the last data if you have a queue).

```
$(function() {
    function update(command) {
        // if you give a command argument to the function, it will send a command
        if (command) {
            $.getJSON('/action?command='+command);
        }
        // then it reads the output
        $.getJSON('/read, {}, function(data) {
        if (data.state !== 'failure' && data.content !== '') {
            $('.notice').text(data.content);
            $('.notice').hide().fadeIn('fast');
            setTimeout(function () { $('.notice').fadeOut('fast'); }, 1500);
        }
        // and rearms the current function so it refreshes the value
        setTimeout(update(), 2); // you can make the updates less often, you don't need to flood your webserver and anyway the arduino reading are blocking
    });
}
update();
});
```

Always use `===` or `!==` in javascript so type don't get coerced. You can call again the function less often
If you do not valuate a javascript argument, it is set to undefined per default.

That's only a little update on what you wrote, it's getting late now, so I hope you'll make something nice out of that!

HTH

Comment: Hey I edited my original post, can you read please, it's very short. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hey one last (I hope) update, the fascination is strong in this one, just see by yourself.

Comment: you know, you should make another question about that last one targeted to javascript audiences. The goal of SO is to make Q&A that can help you, but also help anybody who get here through google. And the more you update your question, the more it gets very specific and unclear, the less it can help users facing similar problems.

Comment: first, you did not read my comment, the `command=0` argument is not usefule `argument` alone works and will be set to `undefined` if you don't give it. Your if condition should be `if (!command)`, not `if (command!=0)`. I'd advice you to add `console.log()` printouts in your function to better understand what's going on. I don't think the `alert()` is directly related to your function not working, but there's another bug besides it. You should make it another question targeted at JS audience. (and restore the question to its previous state, which is already very specific)